# Are 2011 ford fusion headrests interchangeable between option packages?

Tags: ford, interior, fusion

The owner's manual for a 2011 Ford Fusion hybrid described headrests that can be adjusted back and forth in addition to up and down.

Mine does not have them. The non-adjustable ones give my wife a very sore neck.

Am I likely to succeed in swapping them out for fancier ones bought from the parts window? Is there any way to confirm that the more expensive ones can be adjusted to extend less far forward?